# Microsoft Visual Studio binary in Assembly registers

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015

Is there any possibility to display assemlby registers in binary instead of hexadecimal in MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise? I am talking about this window.
[image]

Comment: I don't know, but all those zeroes and ones would quickly make my eyes hurt ;) Just learn how to convert in your head (it's 4 bits for each hex digit)

Comment: I use the Windows calculator. Paste in the hex, and then switch to the binary view. That makes for a nicer presentation of bits, and you can even toggle them on and off by clicking.

Comment: @CodyGray About the calculator.. the Win7 and 8 has "Programmer's view" (Alt+3 I think), where the binary is visible all the time (like here at screenshot: http://www.electronics-micros.com/img/figure/windows7-calculator-binary1.jpg the panel under the edit field shows b63 -> b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly change to binary view, but you can use the [Watch Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) with appropriate [format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx). Even though not documented, you can use `,b` to get binary formatting:

[image: Watch window with binary formatting]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because practically it doesn't help with anything.

If you want to know the binary value of `eax` in your example, it is:

`EAX = 006FFC7C` - read it as "one digit is 4 bits":

0 = `0000`
0 = `0000`
6 = `0110` (6 = 4+2)
F = `1111` (15 = 8+4+2+1)  (BTW this was upper 16 bits of eax)
F = `1111`
C = `1100` (12 = 8+4)
7 = `0111` (7 = 4+2+1)
C = `1100` (12 = 8+4)  (lower 16 bits of eax done)

So as whole: `0000 0000 0110 1111 1111 1100 0111 1100`

If you will do this few times, you will get pretty fluent with it, I have to admit it took me couple of seconds to get for example `C` right, but I'm watching just for particular bit set (like flag-bit), then I usually see it instantly or within 1s.

---

But usually you can evaluate register in Watch/Evaluate window, where the formatting was possible.. I'm not sure about VS2015, but Visual Studio somewhen around year 2000 (when I was working on MS Windows) would maybe manage to display the binary form after entering "eax,b" into watch window (of course I have no means to verify that, nor I'm willing to google VS documentation to see, if it's still possible today, if you *use* VS, then try its help and search for formatting of watch/evaluate in debugger).